# Is there any correlation between Strength and Throwing Range?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack

I've seen other RPG systems that base the thrown range of weapons and objects on Strength score. However, based on what I've seen in the core rules (Javelins and Handaxes, for example), I don't see anything that would allow one character to throw farther than another.

Are there any rules in place for this?

Answer (score 12):

### There is not.

Range in 5e is defined by the weapon and doesn't change with your stats.

Comment: However, stronger characters (who apply their Strength bonus to most thrown weapon attacks) are more accurate at long range. So there is a correlation between strength and long-range _accuracy_.

Answer (score 3):

### Rules-as-Written?

No. The parentheses in the weapons table dictates how far you can reach when you throw the Throwing Axe, Javelin, Dart, Atlatl. So if you're a stickler to the rules like I am, just say *"That's the maximum any humanoid can possibly reach with that weapon and still* possibly *hit."*

---

### But in 5e, you write rules!

> I don't see anything that would allow one character to throw farther than another.

OK, that makes sense and this is what Ability Checks are for:

> **DMG p.237**
>   An Ability check is a test to see whether a character succeeds at a task that he or she has decided to attempt.

I've been a stickler for the rules, mostly because I'm new and are afraid of improvising rules. I've learned recently, though, that if you think it's interesting, you should just let the player attempt it.

Set a DC according to how far the target is and just let the player roll.

A success would mean he can roll an attack, with Disadvantage, of course. A failure means he can't reach that far and automatically misses.

Comment: While this seems done with good intentions, all it's likely to do is slow down the game.

Comment: If a character wants to attack a target outside of the published range for his/her javelin, the game is already slowed down.  This might serve as an object lesson to the players or create an epic tale for the bards to sing about.

Comment: +1 daze413, I find this a creative approach (ability check to get range, followed by actual attack if range is got), but want to point out that this somewhat breaks a 5th ed design pattern of requiring only a single roll to determine an outcome (i.e. in 5th ed you generally only do one of an attack roll, an ability check, or a contest).

Comment: I totally agree with @Derek Stucki and Lexible, but as CharlieHorse says, this would serve as a lesson for the players that: _hey, throwing beyond maximum range is pretty hard and might not be worth it at all, next time I'll just stick with the max ranges but isn't he a cool DM to possibly allow it, instead of just completely shutting the idea down?_